# Windows Azure VM RDP issue

Tags: azure, rdp, azure-virtual-machine

I followed this

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/04/17/step-by-step-build-a-free-sharepoint-2013-lab-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-31-days-of-servers-in-the-cloud-part-7-of-31.aspx#.UX_iF7XvvQI

I created a VM using the datacentre Image it created successfully and the status shows Its running. I am trying to RDP It says

Remote Desktop cant connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:
1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network

make sure the remote computer is turned on and conencted to the network and that remote access is enabled.

I did check the endpoints the public port is open and also 3389 private port is open too. I did try with different release one with latest patch and the other with the second latest OS patch but I am still not able to RDP.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting: I just spun up a brand new vm and cannot rdp either. Could be a transient issue. Nothing shows up on the dashboard, so not sure what the issue is right now... UPDATE: I spoke too soon. I needed to wait for VM status to be Running, not in "Provisioning" state.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah I already figured out firewall in my organization is blocking it. I did update the answer but it did not show up I am trying again :)

Comment: You could give my answer the credit if it was me that first suggested the firewall issue to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your VM has reached the "Running" status. If it's still in one of its pre-running statuses (such as Provisioning), you won't be able to RDP.

Also: Be sure you don't try logging in with 'Administrator' (the default in the rdp login box). Choose localhost\yourusername.

Comment: did you try creating a virtual nw and see whether it opens for you?

Comment: No virtual network. Just a simple standalone virtual machine. And you should start with that as well. Otherwise you have too many 'moving parts' to debug. Make sure you can rdp.

Comment: I am not able to delete my virtual nw because it says it requires time . i will give 10 min - 30 min then I will try to delete it and see if I can do a plain vm

Comment: Nope I tried without any Virtual Networks It did not work. Also verified the port is open and also checked the status was running

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem the other day.  It was solved by going to the Azure Portal, selecting the VM Dashboard, then clicking "Connect" in the grey toolbar at the bottom.  This will download an RDP file that contains the correct connection settings.  You can then send that rdp file to others who you would like to give access to.

I just opened one of the files used to connect, and it looks like the only real difference is the port used.

```
full address:s:[vm name].cloudapp.net:62808
username:s:Administrator
prompt for credentials:i:1
```

I am not sure if all Azure VM's use 62808, but the default RDP port is 3389 so just copying the DNS from the Dashboard into the RDP address will NOT work without adding the correct port.

Comment: I have exactly same settings I even tried with the user I created while creating the VM it does not work. did you do anything special? This is frustrating :(

Comment: Could it be a firewall issue on your end?  This seems like something I'd need to see for myself to figure it out.  If you're up for it, e-mail me at the address in my profile and we can see what's going on.

Comment: What about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049304/windows-azure-rdp-port-forwarding-not-working

Answer (score 1):

One more thing folks should check when having trouble connecting is password length.

I thought I would be all secure by using a guid for a password. RDP worked fine from home (on older XP RDP client), but not from office. At first I thought it was a firewall issue. After verifying with the IT guys that I had full outbound access, I looked a little closer at the RDP error message.

It was saying my credentials were rejected. Finally, I created a second account on the VM and gave it RDP access. I was able to log in fine. The only difference between the two users was this time I didn't bother with a long password.

So I shortened the password on my main account and got in with no problem. I'm not sure what the limit is, but it seems to be less than 32.