# Windows Azure RDP Port Forwarding not working

Tags: azure, endpoint

I am frustrated. And struggling. I have created a service AsifPsCS and then two Vms under it. AsifPsVm1 and AsifPsVm2. The RDP only works if I make In and out ports the same to 3389. If I select any other port such as 3390 or even any other then download the RDP connection file or try to manually connect to it via IP or via the cloud address such as asifpscs.cloudapp.net the RDP will not work. This is frustrating. I just for experiment settled 3389 for in and out both and it worked. now this is the only VM I can connect to. Others are not working. I have also checked ACL there is nothing in the ACL.  And surprisingly in the noon i was connected to the same VM with a really random port. Then i suddenly got DC and after that only the default port 3389 is working for me. I am afraid if Microsoft firewalls are somewhere doing this all.

I have checked all answer on stackoverflow. But they all will ask me to use PUBLIC port to connect instead of private. ETC ETC. Or will ask me to check ACL. Or will ask me to try another port. Or restart machine or even restart service. I have done everything.

Comment: the MS support asked me to disable firewall and delete and recreate port and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your two VMs basically share the same public IP address. Create two rules, one for each vm. 
Rule 1: Public 3399, Private 3389 (target vm1)
Rule 2: Public 3398, private 3389 (target vm2)

This should enable you to access both vms on custom ports. I don't get the "outbound" port part of our question, azure vms are by default all open on outbound traffic.

Comment: I have done the same thing. I have given 3390 and 3391 as public ports and 3389 local ports for each VMs. And I use 3390 and 91 to connect to the VM. No luck.

Comment: are you able to reproduce the error with another set of vms in a separate cloud service? I would assume there's something fishy with your vms.